can reCAPTCHA v3 be implemented to react native?
I want to implement reCAPTCHA v3 to my react native app, since the current configuration: "reCAPTCHA v2" is getting bypassed with AI sometimes and as many articles point out that they are getting solved by third parties for a little money.
I searched for many resources, which are mostly click-bait
so I want to know. does anyone know if it's possible to implement reCAPTCHA v3 and having it run properly. And if so, how do you suggest that I do it?
also according to this link

There are various heuristics which can be used to detect automated systems, such as the number of requests coming from a certain IP, browser fingerprinting, Google account cookies, among many others. Google seems to use some of them. If uncertain, a challenge gets shown.

It says that it depends on google account cookies, which I'm afraid might not be possible since it's a mobile app. I know it says that it depends on many more things. but I'm not sure how they will function in a mobile app.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
